# Python syntax error with function

Tags: python, syntax

My python code wont work for some reason. It says the error is coming from the syntax of the function but im not sure why its doing that

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
four=4
five=5
six=6
seven=7
eight=8
nine=9
ten=10
print "test"
def convert()
  number = raw_input('Enter the number you need converted to binary')
enterYourCommand = raw_input("Enter your command")
if enterYourCommand is "convert"
  convert()
elif enterYourCommand is "tonumber"
  tonumber()
```

Comment: you are missing colons `:` after your `def`, `if` and `elif` statements.

Comment: Besides the colon issue, you will soon discover the difference between `==` and `is`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `:` after function definition and if's:

```
one=1
two=2
three=3
four=4
five=5
six=6
seven=7
eight=8
nine=9
ten=10
print "test"

def convert():
  number = raw_input('Enter the number you need converted to binary')

enterYourCommand = raw_input("Enter your command")

if enterYourCommand is "convert":
  convert()
elif enterYourCommand is "tonumber":
  tonumber()
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the colons after `if`, `elif` and `def`. You have to indent with four spaces. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation) for examples.

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3
four = 4
five = 5
six = 6
seven = 7
eight = 8
nine = 9
ten = 10

enterYourCommand = raw_input("Enter your command")

def convert():
    number = raw_input('Enter the number you need converted to binary')

if enterYourCommand == "convert":
    convert()
elif enterYourCommand == "tonumber":
    tonumber()
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Replace `is` with `==`.

- `is` will return `True` if two variables point to the same object
- `==` will return `True` if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

Sources : [is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: It doesnt have anymore errors but when i enter convert as raw input its asking me for the if statement doesnt detect it and do the convert function. Any ideas why?

Comment: See the edited answer. It uses `==` instead of `is` to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

All python functions should have a colon `:` at the end of their declaration line.

For example:

```
    def convert():
        number = raw_input('Enter the number you need converted to binary')
```

Also, the same is with your `if` and `elif` declarations:

```
    if enterYourCommand is "convert":
        convert()
    elif enterYourCommand is "tonumber":
        tonumber()
```

So, just add `:` at the end of each declaration and you should be good to go.